# flexbox property not working inside nested flexbox whose max-width and flex grow is specified

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm learning CSS and tried to make navbar using flexbox. Used nested flexbox, but "display: flex;" property is not working in ul. I tried to figure out problem with chrome inspect tool and "display: flex" property is disabled in ul.

```css
nav {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between; 
  }
  
  ul {
    border: 1px solid black;
    flex: 1;
    max-width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }
  
  
  ul, li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
```

```html
    <nav>
      <a> Home </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Products</a></li>
        <li><a>Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a>About</a></li>
        <li><a>Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <a> Sign In </a>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because of this:

```
 ul, li {
    display: inline;   <-----
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
```

In line below (order of declarations is relevant), you changed **ul's** `display: flexbox` to `display: inline`.

This way should work :)

```
li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
```